# Identically styled cells from ToBoxes and Cell do not align

Tags: notebooks, alignment

I'm trying to generate some worksheets using `NotebookWrite` so that I can control the page breaks, but have got stuck on the alignment as there appears to be a difference between how `Cell` and `ToBoxes` are treated. Or maybe it's my formatting.

The instructions are text in a Cell with `PageBreakAbove`. Output using `NotebookWrite` without modification. They align with the left margin.

The questions are a row of graphics and text. Output using `NotebookWrite` and `ToBoxes`. They do not align with the left margin.

Styles are the same.

Previously, I collected all the outputs to a variable and created a new notebook; everything lined up fine, but I couldn't control the pagebreaks, hence this approach.

How do I format correctly so everything aligns with the margins?

This is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

hfStyle = {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12, Black, Italic};
leftHeader = Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Left Header", hfStyle]}]];
rightHeader = Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Right Header", hfStyle]}]];
leftFooter = Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Left Footer", hfStyle]}]];
rightFooter = Cell[TextData[{StyleBox[CounterBox["Page"], hfStyle]}]];
bookFormat = {
   PageHeaders -> {{leftHeader, None, rightHeader}, {leftHeader, None,
       rightHeader}},
   PageFooters -> {{leftFooter, None, rightFooter}, {leftFooter, None,
       rightFooter}},
   PageHeaderLines -> {True, True},
   PageFooterLines -> {True, True},
   PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout",
   CellGrouping -> Manual,
   WindowSize -> {737, 613},
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}},
   PrintingCopies -> 1,
   PrintingStartingPageNumber -> 1,
   PrintingPageRange -> {1, Automatic},
   PrintingOptions -> {
     "PaperSize" -> {695, 842},
     "FirstPageHeader" -> True,
     "FirstPageFooter" -> True,
     "PageHeaderMargins" -> {45, 45},
     "PageFooterMargins" -> {45, 45},
     "PrintingMargins" -> {{45, 45}, {0, 56}},
     "PrintCellBrackets" -> False},
   ShowGroupOpener -> False,
   ShowCellLabel -> False,
   FrontEndVersion -> 
     "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (November 20, 2012)",
   StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"};

nb = CreateDocument["", bookFormat, ShowPageBreaks -> True];

a = 0;
t = Table[{h, 0}, {h, 1, 12}];
alignCellStyle = 
  {ImageSize -> Full, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {40, 0}}, TextAlignment -> Left};
alignRowStyle = 
  {ImageSize -> Full, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {40, 0}}, Alignment -> Left};
textRowStyle = {"Text", "Helvetica", Plain, 16};

instructions = 
  Cell[
    TextData[{
      StyleBox[
        "Instructions (controlled page break, text aligned to left   margin)", 
        textRowStyle]}], 
     alignCellStyle, PageBreakAbove -> True];

Table[
  question = 
    Row[{
      ClockGauge[t[[i]], GaugeStyle -> {Blue, Red}, ImageSize -> 120],
      Style["      ______  o'clock   (not aligned to left margin)", 
        textRowStyle]}, 
      alignRowStyle];
  If[Divisible[a++, 4],
     NotebookWrite[nb, instructions]; SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]];
  NotebookWrite[nb, ToBoxes[question]];
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell],
  {i, 1, 8}];
```

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for improving the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[{ToBoxes[question]}]]
```

or

```
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[{ToBoxes@question}, "Input", CellMargins -> {{0, 10}, {5, 10}}]];
```

instead of

```
NotebookWrite[nb, ToBoxes[question]]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem perfectly. Still getting to grips with what can go inside what. Tried putting the question in a cell but not wrapping it all in a cell. Don't understand the use of @ in second solution. Documentation says it's Prefix. I'll keep reading.

Comment: @hadi, my pleasure. Welcome to Mathematica.SE.

Comment: @hadi, `f@x` is same as `f[x]`..